# Testing that a function in a function is being returned

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I have a function which at the end returns another function to be called based on what was done in the first function.

```
function createOption(endPoint, options, body, post) {
  if(!options) {
    options = {
      hostname: 'testurl.com',
      path: '/rest/api/content/' + endPoint,
      port: 443,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': getAuthorization()
      }
   }
   if(body) {
     if(post) options.method = 'POST';
     else options.method = 'PUT';
   }
   else options.method = 'GET';

   return apiCall(options, body)
}

function apiCall(options, body) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var request = https.request(options, function (res) {
        var resBody = '';
        res.on('data', function appendData(responseChunk) {
            resBody += responseChunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function useBody() {
            try {
                var parsed = JSON.parse(resBody);
                if(parsed.statusCode)
                    deferred.reject(new Error('Request failed'));
                else
                    deferred.resolve(parsed);
            }
            catch(error){
                deferred.reject(new Error(resBody));
            }
        });
    });
    if(body)
        request.write(body);
    request.end();
    request.on('error', function (errorData) {
        deferred.reject(new Error('Error making call - :\n' + errorData));
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

module.exports = {
  createOption: createOption,
  apiCall: apiCall
}
```

To test this, I'm trying to assert that apiCall is called using sinon spies, but it won't detect this.

```
var api = require('../src/api');
var chai = require('chai');
var sinon = require('sinon');

var expect = chai.expect;

describe('api test procedure', function() {
  it('should create e based on inputs a, b, c, d and call e', function() {
    var spy = sinon.spy(api, 'apiCall');

    api.createOption('', null, null, null);

    expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? When I'm spying on a function that is called not at the end, it will detect that it's being called, but not at the end.

edit: updated code

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post the *real* code, or at least an extract. In the code you posted, "foo" is declared as a function, and there's no evidence of how it's related to an "api" object. Also, `bar()` is called without any object reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extremely simplified, your code looks like this:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');

function A() {
  B();
}

function B() {
  console.log('hello world');
}

var obj = {
  A : A,
  B : B
};

// Spy on B
var spy = sinon.spy(obj, 'B');

// Call A
A();

// This should be true!
console.log( spy.called );
```

However, it logs `false`.

The reason is that Sinon is spying on `obj.B`, which means that it replaces `obj.B` with another function (the spy) that will call the original `obj.B` and record how it got called (which args, etc).

However, `A` doesn't call `obj.B` at all, it calls `B`. Sure, `obj.B` is a reference to that function, but that doesn't matter: Sinon can only replace `obj.B` with a spy, but not the original `B` as well.

To solve this, `A` should call `obj.B` as well.

Or, in your case:

```
return exports.apiCall(options, body);
```